# How to get an eigenvector of a $3\times 3$ matrix that has first column and a row of zeros

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 0& 0\\
0& 1& 1\\
0& 1& 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

First I got the eigenvalues which are $0$, $1$, $2$.

I tried to get the eigenvectors associated with the above eigenvalues 
but I cannot in case of the eigenvalue $1$ as I got the following matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    0& 0& 0\\
    0& 0& 1\\
    0& 1& 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So, how can I get an eigenvector for this matrix?

Comment: Just by looking at the matrix one can see that $\left(1, \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\right)$ is an eigenpair of the first matrix and the other eigenvalues $0$ and $2$ follow easily.

Comment: I tried online matrix calculator for checking eigen values and was correct.

Comment: @Eng..Abdalmonem $0,2$ and $4$ are not the eigenvalues, sorry.

Comment: Yes i am sorry , you are correct.

Comment: And focusing on the $2\times 2$ right lower submatrix, *suitably*, one can see that $\left(2, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$ is also an eigenpair. Similarly for $\left(0, \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: My problem in how to get an eigen vector associated with eigen value=1

Comment: @ Git Gud sorry what is an eigen pair ?

Comment: It's a pair in which the first entry is an eigenvalue and the second is an eigenvector associated to the first entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RREF of $[A-1I]v_1=0$ is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}v_1 = 0$$

What if we chose:

$$v_1 = (1,0,0)$$

**Update** If we write:

$$ 0a + 1b + 0c = 0 \\ 0 a + 0b + 1 c = 0 \\ 0 a + 0 b + 0c = 0$$

What choices will actually make **all three** equations true and **not** be a zero eigenvector? What if we choose $(a , b , c) = (1, 0 , 0)$? Substitute those values back in and see if it satisfies the system.

Do you see how that satisfies the system? Recall that you cannot have a zero eigenvector. Would any other choice for $b = 1$, or $c=1$ or $b = c = 1$ work? No.

Also, see how this is the null space of the RREF?

Comment: No I do not , can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: and how you got v1=(1,0,0) ?

Comment: Judging from your "last seen" (on this site) datum, you were up WAY TOO LATE last night!  ;-)

Comment: I've done the same. I actually function best (both when I was a student) and onward, when I take a long "nap" (at the end of the work day), then awaken refreshed and working late. (Early rising, late bedtime - but a nice long nap in between!)